# How to get an earlier version of a JS plugin?

Tags: javascript, github

I was just going through [the particles.js project](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js).

I was working on the version 1.1 and now I see that, the project has had a major overhaul and has been changed form 1.1 to 2.0 so, how exactly do I get the 1.1 version of particles.js? There is huge difference between the two 1.1 is just around 500+ lines of code whereas this version seems to be over 1500+ lines of code.

Also the plugin config option differ majorly, is there anyway that I can get the 1.1 version still? I am not a master at understanding GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

There is a release tab in project page

https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/releases

it showcase all version of `particles.js`.

[image]

Comment: how do you navigate to that tab from here https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js

Comment: oh , I will paste a screenshot to tell it.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I post a picture and highlight where  navigate to release tab.

Answer (score 1):

Just navigate between branches in the repo :

[Version 1.1 here](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/tree/1.1.0)

and all the releases of the project

[All releases](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/releases)

You can go to the releases using the information bar :

[image: Branches and releases]

This time you were lucky and this project handles releases and is easy to get an specific version. If you're not so lucky with other repositories then you'll need to check the historial of a project for commits and check what's the commit that belongs to the version that you want :

[image: Search in commits]